# New values are not applied on select options after I input discount code and change the select options

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I have code where a user can select from a dropdown select if they want to buy single product or a pack, and prices are displayed based on the selected option.

But below the select menu I have an input field to apply a discount code. I keep running into a problem where, after applying a discount code, the values of the select menu keep reverting back to the initial prices when I change the selected option.

Here is the form in bootstrap:

```
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-6 mt-2">
        <div class="form-group">
          <select class="form-control form-quantity-select form-quantity-select-'. $product_id .'" id="quantity-select" name="quantity-select" data-field="quantity-select-'. $product_id .'" data-productid="'. $product_id .'">
            <option value="pack" data-value="'.$product['price_pack'].'" selected>Pakovanje</option>
            <option value="single" data-value="'.$product['price_single'].'">Na komad</option>
          </select>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-6 mt-2">
        <h4 class="text-pink text-uppercase total-price brix-bold total-price-'. $product_id .'" data-price-single="'.$product['price_single'].'" data-price-pack="'.$product['price_pack'].'"><span>' . $price_formatted .'</span> RSD</h4>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-12">
        <label for="discount" class="form-label">Popust</label><br/>
        <span>Unesite vaš jedinstveni kod i ostvarite popust prilikom poručivanja</span>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-6 mt-2">
        <div class="form-group">
          <input type="text" class="form-control form-discount" id="discount-'. $product_id .'" name="discount-'. $product_id .'" data-field="discount-'. $product_id .'" data-productid="'. $product_id .'">
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-6 mt-2">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default btn-pink text-uppercase btn-discount btn-block" data-productid="'. $product_id .'">Ostvarite popust</button>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-12">
        <span class="discount-notice-'. $product_id .' text-pink"></span>
      </div>
    </div>
```

And here is the js that I have right now:

```
    $('.form-quantity-select').change(function() {
     var selectedOption = $(this).val();
     var selectedValue = $(this).find('option:selected').data('value');
     console.log(selectedValue);
     var product = $(this).data('productid');
     var formattedPrice = selectedValue.toLocaleString('sr-RS');
     $('.total-price-' + product + ' span').text(formattedPrice);
 });

  $('.btn-discount').on( 'click', function(){
        var product = $(this).data('productid');
    $.ajax({
      dataType: 'json',
      url: coupon_discount.ajax_url,
      data: {
        action: 'coupon_discount',
        discount_code: $('#discount-' + product).val(),
        product_id: product,
      },
      beforeSend: function() {
      },
      success: function(response) {
        if (response.success === false) {
          $('.discount-notice-' + product).html(response.data);
          $('.discount-notice-' + product).slideDown();
        } else if (response.success === true) {
                    var new_price_single = response.data.price_single;
                    var new_price_pack = response.data.price_pack;
                    $('.total-price-' + product).attr('data-price-single', new_price_single);
                    $('.total-price-' + product).attr('data-price-pack', new_price_pack);

                    var productPrice;
                    var newselectedValue = $('.form-quantity-select-' + product).val();
                    if (newselectedValue == 'single') {
                        var productNewPrice = new_price_single;
                    } else {
                        var productNewPrice = new_price_pack;
                    }

            var localeNewPrice = productNewPrice.toLocaleString('sr-RS');
          $('.total-price-' + product + ' span').text(localeNewPrice);

                    var selectOptions = $('.form-quantity-select-' + product + ' option');
                    selectOptions.each(function() {
                          var option = $(this);
                          var value = option.val();
                          if (value == 'pack') {
                            option.attr('data-value', new_price_pack);
                          } else if (value == 'single') {
                            option.attr('data-value', new_price_single);
                          }
                        });

                    $('.discount-notice-' + product).html(response.data.message);
                    $('.discount-notice-' + product).slideDown();
        }
      }
    });
  });
```

Ajax call check the discount code and returns the json success which is for example:

```
{
    "success": true,
    "data": {
        "message": "Uspešno ste uneli kod i ostvarili 20% popusta.",
        "price_single": 80,
        "price_pack": 4336,
        "discount_percentage": "20"
    }
}
```

After that, the current price is updated to discount price, `data-value` in select box is also updated and `data-price-single` and `data-price-pack` are also updated.

Let's say the default values for these variables are:

```
 $product_id = 1; //product no 1
 $product['price_single'] = 100;
 $product['price_pack'] = 5000;
```

So the initial `data-value` for prices would be `100` and `5000` for single and pack, respectively. As you can see from the AJAX response, the new values would be `80` and `4336`.

When I inspect the elements I can see that `data-value`, `data-price-single` and `data-price-pack` attributes are updated, so when I inspect the select menu it should show the new prices:

```
<select class="form-control form-quantity-select form-quantity-select-1" id="quantity-select" name="quantity-select" data-field="quantity-select-1" data-productid="1">
            <option value="pack" data-value="4336" selected="">Pakovanje</option>
            <option value="single" data-value="80">Na komad</option>
          </select>
```

But when I change the option in the browser page the prices are reverted back to `5000` and `100`, like the discount code is not applied at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that you are using `data-*` attributes to store the price on the select options. `data-*` attributes are different from standard attributes in that jQuery does some work to convert the values of these attributes into the logical type and then stores that converted data. For this reason, you should use the [`.data(key, value)`](https://api.jquery.com/data/#data-key-value) method to access these data.

Therefore, you should replace:

```
if (value == 'pack') {
  option.attr('data-value', new_price_pack);
} else if (value == 'single') {
  option.attr('data-value', new_price_single);
}
```

with:

```
if (value == 'pack') {
  option.data('value', new_price_pack);
} else if (value == 'single') {
  option.data('value', new_price_single);
}
```

Comment: O hell no, how did I miss that single thing so easy, I've been busting my head for 3 hours, and this works. Thanks for the help!

Comment: @lonerunner You're welcome. These things happen to all of us!